# Random no of Data in y axis in Google Chart

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, google-visualization

I just started using Google chart, i have already tried column charts with fixed no of columns. But in this new application i need to show random no of data in the y axis. Suppose, there are Week days in x axis, and in y axis i am displaying minutes of calls. i may have different no of calls in a day.

`2014-05-20 0.01,2.45,0.12,0.12,0.12.., .....
 2014-05-21 0.12
 2014-05-22 0
 2014-05-23 0.12,0.12,0.12,0.12,0.12,0.12, .., .....
 2014-05-24 0
 2014-05-25 0
 2014-05-26 2.45`

I don't know which chart to select for this application, Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: you can either group your minutes, or make 1 column for each call, and use stacked columns. From your example, you would have 6 calls max. if other days do not have 6 calls, just fill with null values in those points

Comment: @juvian thanx for the reply, but my no of calls excpecting for a day is not fixed to 6, it may be any no of calls. It would have been easier if number of calls were fixed.. :(

Comment: Yeah, 6 was an example. You need to check your max number of calls and generate that number of columns. The null ones wont make a difference

Comment: Most charts, you would need to know the maximum number of calls per day in order to create a chart with discrete points/bars for each call.  A ScatterChart, however, could show the duration of each call plotted against the date of the call, where each call is a single row of data in your DataTable.  This would not, however, be stackable.

Comment: @asgallant yupp.. i used the same.. thanks for the info.. :)